# Can I create a sidekiq queue from a Rails worker or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, sidekiq

Is there anyway to create a sidekiq queue on the fly from a worker or controller?  I have users on a web app I'm building.  They run background jobs.  I want to be able to have one queue for each user.  So the number of queues is variable.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't the queues are created when the sidekiq is started. There is no way out by which we can configure it at runtime.